# Wildfly Domain shared Topic with HornetQ

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly-8, hornetq, jms-topic

I have a Wildfly cluster in domain mode with two nodes, each one with one server both belonging to the same server group.

I need a shared topic: when a client subscribes to the topic of server A it should be notified also by messages put by server B on the same topic. Right now each client is notified by only the server which is connected to.

I use AWS machines with Linux and I can't use multicast addresses, so I use a punctual protocol expliciting all hosts addresses.
This is my domain.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
                <hornetq-server>
                    <cluster-password>mypassword</cluster-password>
                    <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>

                    <connectors>
                        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                            <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                        </http-connector>
                        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                            <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor-throughput"/>
                            <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        </http-connector>
                        <http-connector name="cnode1" socket-binding="node1">
                            <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                        </http-connector>
                        <http-connector name="cnode2" socket-binding="node2">
                            <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                        </http-connector>
                        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    </connectors>

                    <acceptors>
                        <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor"/>
                        <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor-throughput">
                            <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                            <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                        </http-acceptor>
                        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    </acceptors>

                    <cluster-connections>
                        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                            <address>jms</address>
                            <connector-ref>http-connector</connector-ref>
                            <static-connectors>
                                <connector-ref>
                                    cnode1
                                </connector-ref>
                                <connector-ref>
                                    cnode2
                                </connector-ref>
                            </static-connectors>
                        </cluster-connection>
                    </cluster-connections>

                    <security-settings>
                        <security-setting match="#">
                            <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        </security-setting>
                    </security-settings>

                    <address-settings>
                        <address-setting match="#">
                            <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                            <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                            <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                            <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                            <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
                        </address-setting>
                    </address-settings>

                    <jms-connection-factories>
                        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                        </connection-factory>
                        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                            <ha>true</ha>
                            <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge>
                            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                        </connection-factory>
                        <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                            <transaction mode="xa"/>
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                                <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                        </pooled-connection-factory>
                    </jms-connection-factories>

                    <jms-destinations>
                       ...
                        <jms-topic name="MyNotificationTopic">
                            <entry name="java:/jms/topic/MyNotificationTopic"/>
                        </jms-topic>
                        ...
                    </jms-destinations>
                </hornetq-server>
            </subsystem>
...
<socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
            <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
            ...
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="node1">
                <remote-destination host="172.19.223.x" port="8080"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="node2">
                <remote-destination host="172.19.223.y" port="8080"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
    </socket-binding-groups>
```

Comment: I tried the SAME configuration on windows server machines and it worked! But I can't get them working on linux (AWS) machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the first outbound-socket-binding declaration refers to the node with your domain controller (meaning the domain controller should run on 172.19.223.x, in your configuration). I don't know the reason, maybe it is a wildfly bug, we spent two weeks on this issue and it's still bugging me...